# prevent post to be saved if condition is true in publish_post action

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to write a code to prevent publish post if post title word count to be less than 10. I write the following code:

```
function maxWord($title){ 

    global $post;
    $title = $post->post_title; 

    if (str_word_count($title) >= 10 )
    {
        // Print error and prevent post to be publish
    }

} 
add_action('publish_post', 'maxWord');
```

But I don't know code to prevent post to be publish and how to print error. what can I do?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. It depends upon you how you are managing things i.e. using any framework or core php. And also how want to show the output. There are some hints related to this.

- Use `exit` or `die` - These both will terminate script and print the
  message you want to show. `exit('Message want to show');`
- Return `JSON`, if ajax request - JSON string can be printed as output, if request is ajax like:

  `exit(json_encode['message' => 'Message want to show'])`.
- Redirect and show flash message - This is how most of frameworks do. 
  Store message in session, redirect to error page or other page, show 
  message from session & then clear it.

There might be another ways as well.

Comment: actually I want to use wordpress feature to show error above the text editor without refreshing the page.

Comment: Then you should call the php code through ajax request, return JSON response & handle it with JS.